# array list databind xaml windows 8 unsuccesss

Tags: microsoft-metro

Binding Data to Grid View finding it difficult

```
 if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                List<dashboard1> variable1 = new List<dashboard1>(); 
                var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic arr = JsonParser.Parse(jsonString);
                var items2 = arr[0].items; 
                foreach (var item3 in items2)
                {                      
                    variable1.Add(item3.sectionName);
                    variable1.Add(item3.procedureName);
                    variable1.Add(item3.reportName);
                    variable1.Add(item3.templateName);
                }
               itemGridView.ItemsSource = variable1;
            }
```

parsed json and stored it in list

now i don't know how to bind these values to User Interface please can u help me to continue and pass values to Grid view .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind properties of class `dashboard1` with the UI controls. Suppose you are showing all the properties , in `TextBlock` then bind textbox's text property with property of class `dashboard1`.

So code will be like this.

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding sectionName} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <GridView Grid.Row="2"
        x:Name="itemGridView"             

        SelectionMode="Multiple"                 
         SelectionChanged="itemGridView_SelectionChanged"      >



            <GridView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#7b579b" Tapped="Border_Tapped_1" >
                        <Grid Name="tile" Background="{Binding SubjectTilebackGround}" Height="150" Width="150" Tapped="tile_Tapped_1"  >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="hello2" Text="{Binding SubjectName}" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8"   FontWeight="ExtraLight" Visibility="{Binding isTopSubjectTextVisible}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubjectName}" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8" FontWeight="ExtraLight" Visibility="{Binding isBottomSubjectTextVisible}" />

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="98,0,0,0"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,6"  >
                                <Button
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" Margin="2" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Light" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="( 17 Apps )" Margin="10,2,2,2" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" FontWeight="ExtraLight" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid  Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"   />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </GridView.GroupStyle>
        </GridView>
```

in this example i have added some more useful properties of gridview..and wherever i have used binding like this.

```
Background="{Binding SubjectTilebackGround}"
```

it means "SubjectTilebackGround" is a property present in the class of which objects you have made your list ..means in your case is is DASHBOARD1..so any properties available in your dashboard that you can bind them as i did. hope this will help.